# Get another value with max

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get the maximum value for a field so I used this SQL in a stored procedure

```
Select max(field_1) from mytable into :v_max1
```

However I want also to get another field value with that maximum value, I could write another SQL like this

```
Select field_2 from mytable where field_1 = :v_max1 into v_field2
```

But I want to ask is it possible to get field_2 value with the first statement so I use only single statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will return all records whose `field_1` equals to `MAX(field_1)`

```
SELECT field_2 FROM mytable WHERE field_1 = (
    SELECT MAX(field_1) FROM mytable)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do a query like this

```
SELECT FIRST 1 field_1, field_2
  FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY field_1 DESC;
```

if I remember well you should index by `field_1` in descending order for it to perform well.

note that your second query may return multiple rows if max(value_1) is not unique. this query will return only one row.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are calculating max value not to get the next value for Primary Key field in some table?
This is pretty common mistake and, if so, consider to use generators (sequences) instead, since MAX() is not efficient to organize incremental sequence of values.
Also, remember that MAX() can use only descending index.

Just my 2 cents :)

Regards,
Alexey Kovyazin
IBSurgeon